# Getting the property of a file (last modified date) from user's local system

Tags: jquery, filesystems

I can store the user selected file in localstore using the below code and able to access back whenever user want to reuse it.

In my case I need to get the property (last modified date) of the local file using real path (file:c:\data\test001.txt) before reusing the file from localstore because it might have latest changes. if it has changes I can retrigger the file uploaded to user.

I know we can't read/upload the file using real path (file:c:\data\test001.txt) because of browser limitation.

```
//save the file in local store
var keyFile = 'ButtonFileFull';
localStorage.removeItem(key);                  
var file = $("#systemPath")[0].files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem(keyFile, reader.result);                   
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without the user reselecting the file. Although you can get that date from the [`lastModified` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified) of the `File` instance you're getting from `$("#systemPath")[0].files[0]`, that means...you have to have the user select the file in `#systemPath` again. :-(